# Is there a tool to dump/show event data templates defined in a provider's manifest?

Tags: etw

```
> wevtutil.exe gp <provider-name> /ge /gm /f:xml
```

prints the manifest given a provider, except for its [data templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/wes/defining-event-data-templates). Is there a tool I am missing that would display the templates defined in an installed provider's manifest? They must be out there in the binary WEVT_TEMPLATE resource, since the [Tdh* functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/etw/retrieving-event-data-using-tdh) seem to know about them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Perfview](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567) can do this with this command:

```
PerfView userCommand DumpRegisteredManifest <provider-name>
```

This dumps the complete manifest into an XML.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks a lot!

Comment: perfview internally calls the Tdh functions to decode the data (GetManifestForRegisteredProvider in RegisteredTraceEventParser class from TraceEvent lib)

Comment: Interesting, I also looked at the tool's code with a .NET decompiler and seen this call, but its implementation seems to be in the native code. Anyway, I did not dig deeper as my intention was to simply examine a few Microsoft's own manifests to get a sense of some template practices (e. g. binary data storage). This time I can just use the tool without understanding how it works. :)

Comment: i ran PerfView userCommand DumpRegisteredManifest "IIS: WWW Server" which is a MOF based provider and i got the following error:

Error: Could not find provider with at GUID of 3a2a4e84-4c21-4981-ae10-3fda0d9b0f83

logman can list events just fine for this well known provider

Comment: @AnirudhGoel I have no idea, because I never tried to view the IIS events

Comment: I think I will have to compile perfview with private flags

Comment: @AnirudhGoel you can also create an issue on github about it to get more details/help.

Answer (score 2):

[Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) allows the display of WEVT_TEMPLATE structure.

Comment: Yea it's good to see if an executable has the resource, but it doesn't parse/format the BIN block yet.