# Uninstall event source (ETW) without manifest file?

Tags: c#, etw, eventsource, etw-eventsource

What is the best way to uninstall / delete previously installed event sources without using manifest?

For example.
If I have something like:

```
    [EventSource(Name = "Corporation-Module-X")]
    public sealed class XEventSource : EventSource
    {
        //...
    }
```

For installing event source I am using **wevtutil {im | install-manifest}**

For uninstall is easy if I have the manifest. But could I uninstall event source without having manifest file?

---

I will try to clarify how I am using event sources and why I would like to remove it.

After installing event source using wevtutil, event source is visible as event trace provider. So I can create new Data Collector Set in Performance Monitor where I am adding my event source (together with some performance counters).
It looks like this:

[image: ETW EventSource in new collector set]

What could happen is that event source get renamed or deleted.
E.g. after rename and install using wevtutil.

```
    [EventSource(Name = "Corporation-Module-Y")]
    public sealed class XEventSource : EventSource
    {
        //...
    }
```

Old one is still there in event trace providers:

[image: ETW New event source]

What I would like is to query all installed event providers that start with **Corporation*** and to delete them before installing new one.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: can you uninstall the provider with the dumped manifest?

Comment: I've voted now to close the question as "too broad" because I still have no idea if the dumped manifest works and how else we could help you.

Comment: I am marking your post as the answer since there is not better. It could probably work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to uninstall anything, because a manifest is not registered if you [EventSource](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vancem/2012/07/09/introduction-tutorial-logging-etw-events-in-c-system-diagnostics-tracing-eventsource/). The manifest is sent the [ManifestData Event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52316470/1466046)

[image]

to the listener tool (Perfview, Windows Performance Toolkit) so that they can interpret the recorded data.

When you registered the provider, you can [dump the manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39092214/1466046) and use again wevtutil to remove it.

Comment: I will update my question. Just to clarify why I would like to remove that event source.

Comment: [perfview allows you to dump the manifest of installed providers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39092214/1466046) and now use the manifest for what ever you want